# (React) How to make checkbox UI look checked after mutating state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, concatenation

How to change the UI of the CheckBox component? State mutates finely as I wanted, however the checkbox doesn't look checked after the onCheck call (when click it).

I guess I must create or use an existing props for input objects:

```
    onCheck = item => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
      usage: prevState.usage.concat(item.label, ",")
        }));
        //Todo: Display as checked
      };



    {checkboxes.map(item => (
                  <div className="d-inline-block w-50 p">
                    <CheckBox
                      name={item.name}
                      onChange={this.onCheck.bind(this, item)}
                    />
                    <label key={item.key}>{item.label}</label>
                  </div>
                ))}


    const CheckBox = ({ type = "checkbox", name, checked = false, onChange    }) => (
  <input type={type} name={name} checked={checked} onChange={onChange} />
);
```

Comment: The  `key` property should be on the `<div>` element rather than the `<label>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community, you need to pass checked true/false to the CheckBox component

```
<CheckBox 
name={item.name}
checked={this.state.usage.includes(item.label)}
onChange={this.onCheck.bind(this, item)}
/>
```

Also you don't need to include ',' while concat as it is creating an array
Refer link for reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the checked property and you can use a state to handle it. Let's say `"isChecked"`.

Example:

```
<CheckBox checked={this.state.isChecked} \> (+ your previously added properties)
```

And you'd include something like this in your function:

```
this.setState((prevState) => { isChecked: !prevState.isChecked});
```